# $exception->guards() returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to custmize the unauthenticated function in

App\Exceptions\Handler.php

to redirect users and admins based on the guard , but $exception->guards() returns null , What is the problem ?

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if($request->expectsJson())
        return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);

        dd($exception->guards());
    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

Comment: does `dd($exception->guards());` shows it has `guards()`?

Comment: yes , this what dd($exception) yields:

AuthenticationException {#230 ▼
  #guards: []
  #message: "Unauthenticated."
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers.php"
  #line: 40
  trace: {▶}
}

Comment: hmm, interesting, i noticed that the user is not authenticated yet. perhaps `Guard` is only available if you are authenticated.

Comment: If users are not logged in, how would you know if they are regular user or admin?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Illuminate\Support\Arr;`

In your unauthenticated function you can get Guar.

```
$guard = arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);
```